# vba excel procedure not executing all lines

Tags: vba, excel, execution, onerror

I have created a macro that creates tables, a power point and then copies the tables and pastes them on the slides.
But sometimes, the code skips the line where I copy this table (table.copy).
I can't find any regularity in these lines-skipping.
When I write this line several times, my program runs perfectly. Otherwise, it sometimes stops at the line where it it supposed to paste the table and says "The specified data type is unavailable".
Then I replace the cursor on the previous line ("copy") and it works... until the next time the same happens.
If any one has an idea thanks a lot !

```
Sub CreatePPT()

'Declare the variables
    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oldProduct As String
    Dim Product As String
    Dim MN As String 'month number
    Dim Year As String
    Dim Cluster As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim KPIindex As Integer
    Dim table As Range

'actualisation oldProduct (to be replaced in KPI table)
    oldProduct = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(28, 14)

'Select Global Slicers
    Cluster = InputBox("Cluster")
    MN = InputBox("Please enter month number (ex 05)")
    Year = InputBox("Please enter year (ex 2018)")
    KPIindex = slicerCountry(Cluster)
    slicerDate MN, Year

'Create a new PowerPoint
    Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
    newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add

'Loop on the products
For i = 1 To 6

    'Change slicer and actualisation order type
    Product = slicerProduct(i)

    If i > 1 Then 'close former KPI file
        Name = oldProduct & " KPI.xlsx"
        Workbooks(Name).Close (False)
    End If

    'Open current KPI file, then reactivate working file
    Filename = "C:\Users\moi\Documents\" & Product & " KPI.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (Filename)
    Windows("charlotte.xlsm").Activate

    'actualisation of the europe global KPI table according to the product
    Application.Goto Reference:="KPI"
        Selection.Replace What:=oldProduct, Replacement:=Product, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    oldProduct = Product
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Cells(28, 14) = oldProduct

'Set up KPI local table with the datas imported on KPIs sheet from the corresponding KPI file
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(63, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(18, KPIindex)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(64, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(19, KPIindex)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(68, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(24, KPIindex)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(69, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(25, KPIindex)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(73, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(29, KPIindex)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(74, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(30, KPIindex)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(75, 21) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KPIs").Cells(31, KPIindex)

'Add a new slide for the orders related to the current product (charts & tables & title & comments)
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
    activeSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Product & " - Orders"
    activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Comments"

'Copy the table of top five orders and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
    Set table = Range("top_five")
    table.Copy
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

'Adjust the positioning of the table on Powerpoint Slide
    activeSlide.Shapes(3).Width = 263
    activeSlide.Shapes(3).Left = 230
    activeSlide.Shapes(3).Top = 270


'Copy the table of HTD Orders and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
    Set table = Range("growth")
    table.Copy
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

'Adjust the positioning of the table on Powerpoint Slide
    activeSlide.Shapes(4).Width = 261
    activeSlide.Shapes(4).Left = 230
    activeSlide.Shapes(4).Top = 70

'Copy the table of KPI and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
    Set table = Range("ClusterKPI")
    table.Copy
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

'Adjust the positioning of the table on Powerpoint Slide
    activeSlide.Shapes(5).Width = 200
    activeSlide.Shapes(5).Left = 20
    activeSlide.Shapes(5).Top = 96



    Next

'close the last KPI file opened
Name = oldProduct & " KPI June.xlsx"
Workbooks(Name).Close (False)

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have seen it had been a solution for someone else, but I already verified in my macro settings and "Trust programmatic access to VBA object model" is turned on...

Since this is definitely no proper solution to just copy-paste ten times in a row the same code line hoping one of them won't be skipped, if someone could help me using the "On Error GoTo" tool it would also be a great help, because I tried to write

```
Set table = Range("ClusterKPI")
    table.Copy
    On Error GoTo 135 'where 135 is the number of the previous line
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
```

But it got a Compile error : label not defined.

Thanks again

Comment: Use a label rather than a line number for the target of the `On Error` statement. But: having code that repeatedly executes a line which just threw an error sounds like a recipe for an infinite loop. I can't imagine that this would be robust.

Comment: I now understood that I had to label my line by explicitly writing a number at it's beginning... so now it compiles but it doesn't execute the line even with the code below + 135 at the beginning of the line "table.Copy"... even if it works I agree this is a all but an optimal solution ! Do you think @JohnColeman that this is even worse than copy pasting 6-7 times the line table.Copy ?

Comment: some remarks: Don't use already used names by Excel/VBA' Product, Year, Table as variable-names, you could run into problems. Select is 'never' necessary so try to avoid it, this selecting takes probably to much time.

Comment: thanks for your relevant remarks - this is my first macro so I it helps me a lot ! But what should I write instead of select ? Is it for example better to use SetShapesDefaultProperties ?

Comment: Due to formatting I'll post re-writing of select in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel copies and pastes the data so fast that it needs some time to switch the application.

Try adding the below code before pasting the values

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) '2 represents 2 seconds
```

Comment: With 3 seconds it works perfectly, I suspected something like this but didn't think to slow down the execution with time instead of repeating the code... which is much more clever ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Use an With-End With statement to avoid selecting:

instead of

```
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
activeSlide.Shapes(3).Width = 263
activeSlide.Shapes(3).Left = 230
activeSlide.Shapes(3).Top = 270
```

You could use:

```
With activeSlide
    .Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture
    .Shapes(3).Width = 263
    .Shapes(3).Left = 230
    .Shapes(3).Top = 270
End With
```

And perhaps building in an application.wait isn't necessary

Comment: thanks, in this code it doesn't change much but I will keep in mind this can be a faster solution !